# Media player recognizing Artists as a semi-colon separated list

Tags: software-recommendation, sound, music-player

I am a new user to Ubuntu who has migrated from windows. Though I had tried the previous versions of Ubuntu (and other Linux distros) but it never lasted solely because I'm addicted to a music player, MediaMonkey, which is available for Windows but not for Linux.

It has a plethora of features, one of which is that it recognizes semi-colon (;) delimited artist names as separate artists which makes the overall music experience better. I tried Banshee, Rythmbox and Amrok but none of them seem to have this feature. They all take that text as a single artist which doesn't help.

Is there any music player for Linux that has this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Quod Libet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/)?

It supports multiple values per any tags (backed by the [Mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/) library), and has features to split custom-delimited tags (e.g. using semicolons, slashes, pipes, whatever). Converting your library may be a bit manual unless you use the console plugin to write a small script to do your whole library).

You can get the (older) Ubuntu version easily:

```
$ sudo apt-get install quodlibet quodlibet-plugins
```